# Is there a way to show $_COOKIE in a nice table?

Tags: php, html, cookies

Is there a way to show every cookie in a nice table?
What I have now is:

```
print_r($_COOKIE);
```

cookie set:
`setcookie("$randomGen", "$link", 2147483647);`

Comment: Did you try for,while,foreach etc, ?

Comment: @Niklesh I am not that great with PHP, so i dont know how

Comment: If you just wanna debug the cookies. Most browsers do either have the functionality built right in or have an extension to do what you want to do.

Comment: @César I dont want to debug, i just want to show every cookie that i made.

Comment: @JoostdeNiet It's a functionality of your website to show the user his cookies?

Comment: The minimum you can do is wrap the `print_r()` in a `<pre>`, so `<pre><?php print_r($_COOKIE); ?></pre>`. This way, at least the indentation will be retained and the whole output will definitely be more readable.

Comment: @César Yea, smurl.nl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be the code you need:

```
<?php

function print_cookies() {
  echo '<table>';
  foreach ($_COOKIE as $key => $value) {
    echo '<tr><td>' . $key . '</td><td>' . $value . '</td></tr>';
  }
  echo '</table>';
}
```

I wrote this off of the top of my head and without testing. But it should do what you need. It's really simple.

Disclaimer: This should not be used in production. But since you don't seem to get this code together by yourself I suppose that you won't mind it.

Answer (score 0):

If your PHP version support var_dump() built-in function,
You can try to use var_dump($_COOKIE) to view it's element;